# Populate Custom Ordering/Sorting woocommerce

Tags: php, html, sorting, post, woocommerce

I'm trying to figure out on how to populate my custom ordering inside my custom template page.

Here is my work in progress. So far the output shows a select box with empty values. When I check the view source i saw this error.

**Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Users\Noel\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\lumiere\wp-content\themes\klasik\lumiere-products-page.php on line 23**

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'product_cat' => 'Lumiere', 'orderby' => 'rand' );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>


    <?php //Woocommerce Custom Ordering ?>
    <form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">
        <select name="orderby" class="orderby">
        <?php foreach ( $catalog_orderby_options as $id => $name ) : ?>
             <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $id ); ?>" <?php selected( $orderby, $id ); ?>><?php echo esc_html( $name ); ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>

       <?php
        // Keep query string vars intact
        foreach ( $_GET as $key => $val ) {
        if ( 'orderby' === $key || 'submit' === $key ) {
            continue;
        }
        if ( is_array( $val ) ) {
            foreach( $val as $innerVal ) {
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '[]" value="' . esc_attr( $innerVal ) . '" />';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $val ) . '" />';
             }
        }
        ?>
    </form>


            <li class="product product-items ">    

                    <div class="product-item">

                    <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>

                    <div class="product-thumbnail">
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" />'; ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h3>
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        </h3>


                        <h4 class="product-category-title">
                        <?php
                             $size = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) );
                             echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . ' ', '.</span>' );
                        ?>
                        </h4>

                        <?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>
                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>


                        <?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
                            <span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>  


                    <div class="product-rating">
                        <?php if ($average = $product->get_average_rating()) : ?>
                            <?php echo '<div class="star-rating" title="'.sprintf(__( 'Rated %s out of 5', 'woocommerce' ), $average).'"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' ).'</span></div>'; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>

                    <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>

                    </div>

                </div>



            </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul><!--/.products-->
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() is an error that comes up when you are trying to read a variable that isn't an array as an array

Comment: try using is_array in the problematic line

Comment: line 23 is this code. <?php foreach ( $catalog_orderby_options as $id => $name ) : ?>

Comment: then check if $catalog_orderby_options is an array

Comment: You're not even creating $catalog_orderby_options before you try to iterate it'

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not very familiar with PHP. Basically what i'm trying to do is put a default sorting function just like in the shop page in a custom archive page.